# Saving data on intermediary table on server

Tags: c#, sql, azure

As example in project there are tables WorkReason and WorkAreas. There is EFModel it includes WorkReason and WorkArea. We can add WorkReason and WorkArea to SQL but I can't add WorkReasonWorkAreas there. How can I do it? The table WorkReasonWorkAreas created for connection of WorkReason and WorkAreas.

The code below shows that WorkReason and WorkAreas are in the EFModel.

```
public partial class WorkReason
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public WorkReason()
    {
        this.Dates = new HashSet<Date>();
        this.WorkAreas = new HashSet<WorkArea>();
        this.WorkTypes = new HashSet<WorkType>();
    }

    public int WorkReasonID { get; set; }
    public int PlannedWorkID { get; set; }
    public int ClientManagerID { get; set; }
    public int ProfesionID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int StatusID { get; set; }

    public virtual PlannedWork PlannedWork { get; set; }
    public virtual Profession Profession { get; set; }
    public virtual Status Status { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Date> Dates { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<WorkArea> WorkAreas { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<WorkType> WorkTypes { get; set; }
}

public partial class WorkArea
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public WorkArea()
    {
        this.WorkReasons = new HashSet<WorkReason>();
    }

    public int WorkAreaID { get; set; }
    public int JobLocationID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual JobLocation JobLocation { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<WorkReason> WorkReasons { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What's your error? You can't add it in the model? Did you use Code first or DatabaseFirst?

Comment: yes, all fixed.thank you